# Run _.each inside while PARSE

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I have a table named "circle" and it represents mailing list.
Circle can contain user id in invitedUser or circle id in invitedCircle.
I need to get all circles id that contain specific user (in the code: 1-9).
For example if studantA is in CircleA
CircleA is in CircleB
so i need to get for studantA as output CircleA and CircleB.

I try to find all circles who conect each others by while and each, but the status of the job is : Could not connect to Cloud Code.
How can I run this query until no result found?

```js
Parse.Cloud.job("fillMemberInCircles", function (request, status) {

    var studentId = "123456789";
    var output = [];
    var lowLayer = [];
    var highLayer = [];

    // Get circles when the student appears in column invitedUsers
    var invitedUsers = new Parse.Query("circles");
    invitedUsers.equalTo("invitedUsers", studentId);
    invitedUsers.find({
        success: function (invitedUsersResults) {

            if (invitedUsersResults.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < invitedUsersResults.length; i++) {
                    output.push(invitedUsersResults[i].id);
                    lowLayer.push(invitedUsersResults[i].id);
                }

                var counter = lowLayer.length;
                var _ = require('underscore.js');
                
                while (counter > 0) {
                    //var _ = require('underscore.js');
                    _.each(lowLayer, function (currCircle) {

                        var invitedCirclesQuery = new Parse.Query("circles");
                        invitedCirclesQuery.equalTo("invitedCircles", currCircle);
                        invitedCirclesQuery.find().then(function (results) {
                            if (results.length != 0) { // item exists
                                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                                    if (output.indexOf(results[j].id) == -1) {
                                        output.push(results[j].id);
                                        highLayer.push(results[j].id);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }).then(function () {
                            counter--;
                            if (counter == 0) {
                                if (highLayer.length == 0) {
                                    console.log("OK");
                                    lowLayer = [];
                                    status.success("SUCSESS: " + output.length.toString());
                                } else {
                                    lowLayer = highLayer;
                                    counter = lowLayer.length;
                                    highLayer = [];
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }

            //status.success("SUCSESS: " + output.length.toString());
        },
        error: function () {
            status.error("[fillMemberInCircles] There was some error with queryMajors");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: You need to wait for all of the promises. http://blog.slaks.net/2015-06-10/advanced-promise-usage/